# What is the time complexity of pandas groupBy function?

Tags: pandas

I tried finding it, but couldn't find it anywhere. This article I read about group by says that groupBy works by splitting and binning the items, but I couldn't convincingly guess the time complexity.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pandas-groupby/

I also looked up groupBy's implementation, but I couldn't make sense of it sadly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Splitting the groups is `O(n)` with `n` the number of rows.

Since [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) sorts the groups by default, assuming `k` the number of unique groups, the complexity is `O(n + k*log(k))`, which is why the documentation recommends "*Get better performance by turning this off*".